# Tubeless tire looses air through weld of rim

Tags: tire, rims, tubeless, sealant

I have the [DT Swiss X1700 Spline 29″](https://www.dtswiss.com/Wheels/MTB-Wheels/X-1700-Spline-TWO-29) with the [Schwalbe RockRazor 2.35" PaceStar](http://www.schwalbe.com/en/offroad-reader/rock-razor.html) on my pre built Bike which are tubeless. After about 100 km the tire now looses air through the weld very fast.

I illustrated it appropriately:

[image]

Can you tell me if this is a factory fault or is it simply not enough sealant in it? Does the sealant work on the rim as well? I don't want to take a look into it since I may lose warranty.

Comment: That is described as a tubeless ready rim.  Do you have tubeless kit installed?  I am not asking a about the tire - a kit.

Comment: I bought it already put together from a big bike company, so I guess yes.

Comment: Pull the tire.  It has a kit or not.   DT has kits on their web site.

Comment: Of course it wasn't tubeless. The guy from the shop told me that it is normal to deliver tubeless ready rims with tubes due to the long time they are stored before shipped. The milk would stop working before delivery.

Comment: So you go from "guess yes" to "of course it wasn't"  and you still have not answered the simple original question of "Do you have tubeless kit installed?"   I give up.

Comment: The kit was not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've only done 100 km on it, its under warranty so take it back.

Sealant may fix it for now, but a weld shouldn't leak air, so its a weak spot on the rim.